# jQuery based Splitter plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to create a layout as below;

[image]

Now as you can see, I want resizable cells around Cell-center i.e for cell-left and cell-right

I was using the jQuery plugin at http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html
to achieve the same.

But I also needed to create 4 portlets (as you can see for cell-center) . I used jQuery UI for the same and for some reasons, the 2 are not going very well (3cSplitter and jQuery UI Portlets)...the layout gets broken completely...not sure if it has to do with absolute positioning...

But my question is, can I use jQuery UI to acheive similar kind of splitter. The  one that I saw under http://jqueryui.com/resizable/
does not seem to be very good for what I want as http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html
If both are jQuery UI based, I guess the integration issues would not be much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [jQuery Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm) plugin offers this functionality. In conjunction with jQuery UI, you get resizable panes with very minimal markup. To achieve what you are looking for, you would simply need some markup like:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="ui-layout-west">Left</div>
  <div class="ui-layout-center">Center</div>
  <div class="ui-layout-east">Right</div>
</div>
```

With the default configuration, you simply can instantiate the plugin with the default styling:

```
$("#container").layout({
  applyDemoStyles: true
});
```

And you have a pane view with resizable panes. The plugin is fairly configurable, allowing you to style the pane handlers to your liking as well as configuring functional aspects of the plugin such as minimum or maximum sizes of panes. Additionally, for more complex views, you can nest layout panes with other panes and instantiate the plugin multiple times.

Comment: Thx a lot...Using this plugin, can I configure such that if I have a North cell (cell-top) and I do not want any splitter there..I only want resizable cells around Cell-center i.e for cell-left and cell-right...How can I configure that ?

Comment: Also how standard is jQuery Layout plugin ? Is it used professionally ?

Answer (score 3):

You would like something like [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/rQZ8Z/2/) ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="center">
    <div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>
    <div class="column">

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">Feeds</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

  <div class="portlet">
    <div class="portlet-header">News</div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.left, .right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 170px;
    float: left;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
.left {
    border-right: 3px solid #DDD;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.right {
    border-left: 3px solid #DDD;
    left: 0!important;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
.center {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.column { width: 50%; float: left; padding-bottom: 100px; }
.portlet { margin: 0 1em 1em 0;}
  .portlet-header { margin: 0.3em; padding-bottom: 4px; padding-left: 0.2em; }
  .portlet-header .ui-icon { float: right; }
  .portlet-content { padding: 0.4em; }
  .ui-sortable-placeholder { border: 1px dotted black; visibility: visible !important; height: 50px !important; }
  .ui-sortable-placeholder * { visibility: hidden; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var maxBorderCellWidth = 250;
    var minBorderCellWidth = 150;
    var resizeCenter = function () {
        var clientWidth  = $(document).innerWidth();
        var leftWidth = $( ".left" ).outerWidth(true);
        var rightWidth = $( ".right" ).outerWidth(true);
       console.log(clientWidth); $('.center').width(clientWidth-leftWidth-rightWidth);
    }

    $( ".left" ).resizable({
      maxWidth: maxBorderCellWidth,
      minWidth: minBorderCellWidth,
      handles: 'e',
      resize: function (event, ui){
          resizeCenter();
      }
    });
    $( ".right" ).resizable({
      maxWidth: maxBorderCellWidth,
      minWidth: minBorderCellWidth,
      handles: 'w',
      resize: function (event, ui){
          resizeCenter();  
      }
    });
    $( ".column" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".column"
    });

    $( ".portlet" ).addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
      .find( ".portlet-header" )
        .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
        .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
      .find( ".portlet-content" );

    $( ".portlet-header .ui-icon" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-minusthick" ).toggleClass( "ui-icon-plusthick" );
      $( this ).parents( ".portlet:first" ).find( ".portlet-content" ).toggle();
    });

    $( ".column" ).disableSelection();

    resizeCenter();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        console.log("test");
        resizeCenter();
    });
});
```

Comment: @testndtv This should be the answer, I think exact as per requirement.

Comment: Thx a lot...For some reasons, I am getting a jerky behavior...e.g. the left cell suddenly resizes...I am not seeing a live resize as I move my mouse ...

Comment: Also in IE 8, the 3rd col (Right) is going down/below the left col as soon as I move...

Comment: Normally the problem with ie8 is solved on this version (http://jsfiddle.net/rQZ8Z/9/) but I cannot test...
I don't know what is the cause of jerky that works fine here.